# How do I get Nautilus to let me copy and paste a folder?

Tags: nautilus, samba, directory, paste

When copying a file from a network share (SMB on my Macbook) using Nautilus, I get an error complaining, "Error while copying '*Folder-name*.' 'X' is a folder. I know that I'm copying a folder, and that's what I want. I can copy files one by one or in groups of files, but not entire folders. So I have to believe that it's not related to permissions. I know how to copy things using the command line, but that sort of negates having a GUI and is making things much more complicated than they should be. I've tried dragging and dropping, copy and paste, and "Copy to:" in the context menu, all to no avail. I'm sure this is something simple, but after searching for an answer on Google for the past 40 minutes (and finding only other problems related to permissions, while copying from the command line), I just had to ask. Any help is much appreciated.

better screenshot (thanks for the tip):
[image: http://imgur.com/9CFIdp1]

Comment: Done. Thanks for the tip, I had assumed that if I couldn't add a pic it wasn't going to let me add links to one. Silly me.

Comment: I managed to get the folder I needed (then) copied using the Macbook to copy the files to Ubuntu, but I'd still like to know how to make this work properly from Ubuntu in the future.

Comment: It still could be a permissions problem; folders have permissions that are different than files.  Ownership is included.  It's possible that you, on Ubuntu, are not the owner of the folder, or the container for the folder.